# R: assigning to variable class of the element of data frame

Tags: r, class, dataframe

I am writing a function in R .It assigns to "y" class of the element of dataframe. Here is my function with example.

```
f=function(x,data) {
   y=class(eval(substitute(x),data))
   print(y)
}

d=data.frame(a=1,b=2)

f(a,d)
[1] "numeric"
```

Can I use anything else instead of class(eval(substitute(x),data)) ?

Comment: Hi Marina, You print not return the value (which is not the same) in the function. Second, what do you want to achieve? It is quite obscure for me to understand what you want to do

Comment: I want to get the same as now another way. Y should be class of the column from data frame.

Answer (score 1):

It could work in this way... With a slight modification on how you use `f()`

```
f = function (x, data) {
  y = lapply(data,class)
  print(y[[x]])
}

d <- data.frame ( a=1, b=2)

f("a",d)
```

That is generic and could be used for all columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you want class of each column attached to your data frame as new column. Please use below code

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(a = c(1:3),b = c("A","B","C"), c = as.factor(c("G","H","H")),stringsAsFactors = F)
class_df = lapply(df,class) %>% bind_rows()
names(class_df) = paste0(names(class_df),"_class")
df = cbind(df,class_df)
```